# Integral form of Euler's constant

Tags: analysis, euler-mascheroni-constant

For the integral:

$$-\gamma = \int_0^\infty \!\! e^{-u} \ln u\,\mathrm du = \int_0^1 \!\! e^{-u} \ln u\,\mathrm du + \int_0^\infty \!\! e^{-u}\ln  u \,\mathrm du $$  $$ =[(-e^{-u} +1)\ln u]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \!\! \frac {(-e^{-u}+1)}{u}\,\mathrm du + [-e^{-u}\ln u]_1^\infty \!\!
- \int_1^\infty \!\! \frac{-e^{-u}}{u}\,\mathrm du$$

When I integrate by parts on the two integrals I get:
$$\int_0^1\!\! e^{-u}  \ln u \,\mathrm du = [-e^{-u} \ln u]_0^1 + \int_0^1 \!\!\frac{ e^{-u}}{u} \,\mathrm du +[-e^{-u}\ln u]_1^\infty \!\! -\int_1^\infty \!\! \frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,\mathrm du $$
I don't see where on the first of the two integrals
$$ [(-e^{-u} +1)\ln u]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \!\! \frac{(-e^{-u}+1)}{u} \,\mathrm du $$  comes from.
It is the $$ -e^{-u} +1 $$ that keeps messing me up.

Comment: after I said when I integrate by parts I made a mistake on the left of the equal sign the limits should be 0 to infinity.

Comment: Here we chose $C-e^{-u},C=1$ for the primitive of $e^{-u}$ in order to make $(C-e^{-u})\log u \vert_0^1$ well-defined. This is also why we can't integrate by parts $\int_0^\infty e^{-u} \log (u ) du$ directly as $(C-e^{-u})\log u \vert_0^\infty$ diverges in every case.

Comment: I am not sure what primitive means.

Comment: antiderivative ${}$